# Change notehead size depending on note duration

Tags: lilypond

I'm trying to create a function that changes the note head font-size depending on the duration of the note. For example, if the note is a whole-note, then its note head should have double size.

I haven't found anything in the lilypond snippets that is even close. I was trying something like this, but for some reason the argument grub is not passed.

```
#(define (size-notehead grob)
   (duration-to-size
    (ly:event-property (event-cause grob) 'duration)))

applyNoteHeadSize = {
  \override NoteHead.font-size = #size-notehead
}
```

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: `scheme` means a programming language.

Comment: I know scheme is a programming language, it is the language used by Lilypond and as you can see it is being used in the example I added

Comment: The question does not concern the language however.  Scheme is the "official" language for scripting gnu/linux applications and there are hundred of applications written in scheme.  This question does not concern the #scheme as it is not specific to the language, but to some application.